# SQL: Removing rows from Select Statement on Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

I have a stored procedure that returns a table of items that are missing for a specified ID. For example: `exec getMissingItems '1'` will return a list of the items that are missing for `ID = 1` such as : `'A', 'B', 'C'`. Now I am tracking when these items are received so they are stored into the database as `'A Received'` & `B received` and so forth. I want to be able to only show the items that have not yet been received, for instance if I call `exec getMissingItems '1'` now, it will only return `'C'`.

All of the information is being stored into a database table

```
TABLE1
ID |  Event
1  | A Missing
1  | B Missing
1  | C Missing
1  | A Received
1  | B Received
```

So currently getMissingItems is simply calling:

`SELECT Event FROM TABLE1 WHERE Event LIKE '%Missing'`

Which returns a table of the items missing, but still returns them even if they are missing

```
RETURNED TABLE
   Event
A Missing
B Missing
C Missing
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some schema information? Maybe even make a proof of concept on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: You will need to be more specific when describing your schema design.  At first glance, it appears a simple join would suffice.

Comment: Is it being returned as a table or is it one string of 'A', 'B', 'C'

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code, hopefully it's clear enough now.

Comment: You are placing two informations in one column. This is breaking 1st normal form. Value 'A missing' should be two values in separate columns, like Item=A and EventType=missing.

Comment: Agreed, but sadly I cannot change this because I did not design the table to be like this, not can I change it. I simply have to work with what's given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you.  You need to left join based on the ID and the parsed identifier from the event.  Then find the rows that are unmatched that have "Missing" in the event.

Here is a SQL fiddle link to this example -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d668/1/0

```
create table #table1
(
    ID int,
    [Event] varchar(100)
);

go

insert into #table1 values (1, 'A Missing');
insert into #table1 values (1, 'B Missing');
insert into #table1 values (1, 'C Missing');
insert into #table1 values (1, 'A Received');
insert into #table1 values (1, 'B Received');

go

with cte as
(
    select id, [Event], substring([Event], 1, patindex('% %', [Event]) -1) as ItemId
    from #table1
)

select a.Event
from cte a
    left join cte b on 
        a.id = b.id and                 -- IDs must match
        a.ItemId = b.ItemId and         -- the ItemId from the parsed Event must match on the left side
        a.Event like '%Missing' and     -- items that match have a 'Missing' on the "left"
        b.Event like '%Received'        -- items that match have a 'Received' on the "right"
where b.ID is null                      -- rows that did not match on the right
and a.Event like '%Missing'             -- row has missing in the event on the left side


drop table #table1;

go
```

Comment: Thanks! You're a life saver. So much work for a seemingly minuscule task.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited answer**

See if this works a little better for you...

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id, event, missing, recieved)
INSERT INTO #temp 
SELECT Id, Event, case when event like '%missing%' then 1 else 0 END 
CASE WHEN event like '%recieved%' then 1 else 0
 FROM TABLE1 

SELECT Event from Table1 t join #temp tt on t.id = tt.id
WHERE missing =1 and recieved = 0
```

Comment: This still returns A B and C, just not the events that actually contain 'Received'. If there is an event 'A Received', I don't want it to show 'A Missing' either.